# Create recursive method to loop over entities classes and their collections

Tags: c#, reflection, recursion, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I'm working in EF Code-First approach in my application, and I have many entities classes that contains ICollection objects.  My aim is to run over the entities and their collections in a recursive-manner in order to build up a tree(using json & jsTree).

I supposed I need reflection here...

Today I'm doing it using few inner foreach loops in order to achieve my need but it seems to me as a very bad approach because I think I can reduce it to much smaller amount of code lines.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Smaller amount of code is not always the better one.

Comment: In my case I do believe that reducing six foreach loops to one is better. the question is how.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the [ObjectWalker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectmanager.aspx).

This can help you to process a complete graph without duplicates. You could extend this to serialize to JSON.